# How do I transform this challenge in JS?

Tags: javascript, transform, transition

How do I transform this challenge into JS:

Create a div, a button, and a text field. Give the div a red background so you can see it, and give it a starting width and height of 100px.

When the button is clicked, the width and height of the div should smoothly transition to whatever value is in the text field.

For example, if the user types 40px in the text box and clicks the button, the width and height of the div should smoothly transition to 40px.

Please tell me where I'm coding wrong:

```js
let testBox = document.getElementById("test_box");
testBox.className = "testBoxStyles";
let transitionValue = document.getElementById("transitionValue").value;
document.getElementById("transition").onclick = function() {
  testBox.style.transform = "translateX(" + (transitionValue) + "px)";
};
```

```css
.testBoxStyles {
  transition: all 0.2s;
  background-color: coral;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test_box">TEST BOX</div>
<input id="transitionValue" type="text">Transition Value</input><br />
<button id="transition">Transit Test Box Smoothly</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could transition `max-height` and `max-width`:

```js
let testBox = document.getElementById("test_box");
testBox.className = "testBoxStyles";
let transitionValue = document.getElementById("transitionValue");

document.getElementById("transition").onclick = function() {
  testBox.style.maxWidth = transitionValue.value;
  testBox.style.maxHeight = transitionValue.value;
};
```

```css
.testBoxStyles {
  transition: all 0.2s;
  background-color: coral;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test_box">TEST BOX</div>
<input id="transitionValue" type="text">Transition Value<br />
<button id="transition">Transit Test Box Smoothly</button>
```

---

With `transform: translate`:

```js
let testBox = document.getElementById("test_box");
testBox.className = "testBoxStyles";
let transitionValue = document.getElementById("transitionValue");

document.getElementById("transition").onclick = function() {
  testBox.style.transform = `translateX(${transitionValue.value})`;
};
```

```css
.testBoxStyles {
  transition: all 0.2s;
  background-color: coral;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test_box">TEST BOX</div>
<input id="transitionValue" type="text">Transition Value<br />
<button id="transition">Transit Test Box Smoothly</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, Dan..! it makes sense to me now. what if I have to move only the test box, not with the height and width.

Comment: No problem, same idea just interpolate it like this: `translateX(${transitionValue.value})`

Comment: Important to note: `transitionValue.value` needs to be evaluated inside the click function, otherwise, the value is stored on page-load and will be empty.

Comment: that's awesome it works now..! thanks for the explanation..! you are the best..!